# Is wolframalpha wrong (Plotting inequalities)

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I just wanted to plot a simple inequality: $$-x \geq 4$$ and wolframalpha gives me the following plot:[image]

But I think it should look like this:

[image]

Am I correct? If so why is wolframalpha producing such plots?

**N.B.** To reproduce the plot, enter $\textit{plot -x >= 4}$ at the wolframalpha website.

Comment: $$-x\ge 4\iff x\le-4$$ so WA is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, Wolfram Alpha is right.

The plot by Alpha shows the graph of the two functions $f(x)=-x$ and $g(x)=4$ to let you compare them visually.

It has no reason to show a $XY$ map of the Boolean function $-x\ge4$, as there is no $y$ variable.

Comment: On the other hand, ``plot x < y+4`` produces a plot of the obvious region in the $x,y$ plane. And ``plot  x > 4 and y>2`` produces a region bounded below by the line $y=2$ and on the left by the line $x=4$. But setting aside the question of _why_ one would want to specify a planar region bounded by only a single vertical or horizontal line, it doesn't seem to be possible to do so in Alpha.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Changing the fuction to $-x \geq 4 + (0\cdot y)$ would introduce a $y$ variable, but wolframalpha produces the same image; so I don't think that is the reason.

Comment: @Ragnar: don't be bad faith. There is no $y$ in your question, Alpha has no reason to introduce one. Regarding your second example, Alpha is obviously smart enough to see that there is no dependency on $y$. Try plot -x>=3+(|y|+0.001)/(|y|)